# Python definition not working using list comprehension

Tags: python, function, list-comprehension

I'm using python to write a programme for poker following a course on Udacity. One of the definitions i'm using is the following which i'm using from the course.

```
def card_ranks(cards):
"Return a list of the ranks, sorted with higher first."
    ranks = ['--23456789TJQKA'.index(r) for r,s in cards]
    ranks.sort(reverse=True)
    return ranks
```

So this is meant to for example cards_ranks([TH,9C,9D,7S]) should return [10,9,9,7]. However i'm getting the following error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-13-ff8fb242bb41> in <module>()
----> 1 card_ranks(['9H','8C','7C','10D'])

<ipython-input-12-7eaf1ab781bc> in card_ranks(cards)
      1 def card_ranks(cards):
      2     "Return a list of the ranks, sorted with higher first."
----> 3     ranks = ['--23456789TJQKA'.index(r) for r,s in cards]
      4     ranks.sort(reverse=True)
      5     return ranks

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Does anyone know how to fix it? Btw i'm new to list comprehension i did try the following myself which works if only numbers in the cards are used

```
def card_ranks(cards):
    "Return a list of the ranks, sorted with higher first."
    ranks = [r[0] for r in cards]
    ranks.sort(reverse=True)
    return ranks
```

So naturally i tried

```
def card_ranks(cards):
        "Return a list of the ranks, sorted with higher first."
         ranks = ['--23456789TJQKA'.index(r[0]) for r in cards]
         ranks.sort(reverse=True)
         return ranks
```

But that also did not work. I would really appreciate any help, the code is meant to work but it does not when i'm using it. I'm using a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: how are you calling `card_ranks`?

Comment: Hint: when the string is "10D", how is Python supposed to decide how to split that up into `r` and `s`?

Comment: `cards` is a list, so you can only have one variable iterate over it. You cannot split it at the same time into characters like that. Also, the problem with `r[0]` is that this is just the `'1'` for the value `'10D'`. You will have to add a bit more logic on splitting those values.

Comment: I think this would work, if you use `'TD'` instead of `'10D'`.

Comment: You should try to use another data-type instead of *string* to represent your cards. `str` objects are meant to represents strings, not cards. This is a natural case for a class, or using `Enums` to represents suits etc. Check out [this implementation I made for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399384/5014455)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You are trying to `unpack` into too few variables.

In the `list comprehension`:

```
ranks = ['--23456789TJQKA'.index(r) for r,s in cards]
```

You are [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) each `card` in `cards` into the variables `r` and `s`. To simplify this, you can just assign `variables` in the same way:

```
a, b = "xy"
```

so now `a` is `'x'` and `b` holds `y`.

However, your problem is arising from the last `card` in the `list`: `10D`. You are trying to `unpack` this `card` with `3` `chars` into only `2` variables. This can again be simplified as trying to do:

```
a, b = "10D"
```

which throws the same `ValueError` you got:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

which actually makes complete sense when you understand what you are trying to get the computer to do.

To fix this `error`, simply pass in the card value as `TD` instead of `10D` which will allow it to be `unpacked` correctly into the `2` variables: `r` and `s`:

```
r, s = "TD"

# r <-- "T"
# s <-- "D"
```

This should get rid of your `error` and the `function` will output correctly. **:)**

Answer (score 3):

The value `'10D'` is a sequence of three characters, which is too many values to unpack into `r,s`.

It should work if you use `'TD'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Last code you did is right. But you have a small mistake. 
Looks like you have '10D' card. So when you execute `r[0]` you get '1'. 
But you don't have this case in your index string. So `'--23456789...'.index(r[0])` rise an exception.

Right code will be something like this*:

```
def card_ranks(cards):
    "Return a list of the ranks, sorted with higher first."
     ranks = ['--234567891TJQKA'.index(r[0]) for r in cards]
     ranks.sort(reverse=True)
     return ranks
```

* (depends on which index should have 10 card and which another cards (T, J, Q, K, A)